# In vim, how to display runtimepath value in echo or echomsg?

Tags: vim

I have modified the `'runtimepath'` in my `.vimrc` file.
As I am having problems of not found files, I would like to display the `runtimepath` value in an `:echo` or `:echomsg`

I already know about he existence of `:scriptnames` and the possibility of checking the value with `:set runtimepath`, but I specifically need to display it with `:echo` or `:echomsg` commands.

I have already tried, without success, the following:

- `:echo runtimepath`
- `:echo expand(runtimepath)`
- `:echo expand('runtimepath')`

Answer (score 0):

Everyting that is set using `:set` is an option in vim.
Options are described in the help between single quotes, like in `:h 'runtimepath'`

If you check the documentation page `:h after-directory` (which is right after `:h 'runtimepath'` ), it is said:

> More entries are added when using |packages|.  If it gets very long
> then `:set rtp` will be truncated, use `:echo &rtp` to see the full
> string.

Therefore, the answer to the question is:

`:echo &runtimepath`